# Stripping time information in a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there any better way to strip the time information in a DateTime Object than creating a new DateTime Object? For example, if I just want today's date and not time, is the only way is to do the following?

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime Today = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
```

Comment: Simple Google Search rendered this link [DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Lyle'sMug Date will return the date, with the time set to midnight.

Comment: Oh right. That's what OP is asking for.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Right now, your question is in danger of being closed because it hardly has any code at all, while we like to review entire sections at once.  Could you please post more code so we can see the context you are using this in?

Answer (score 3):

Simple Google Search rendered this link [DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

this Returns only the date

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.Date.ToString("d"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw that property but easily misjudged its use when I saw its type. I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Today](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Now`.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

Console.WriteLine(today);
```

This results in

> 4/14/2015 12:00:00 AM

For a more general solution, use the [Date property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DateTime today = someUnknownDateTime.Date;
```